# Can you use Swornbreaker more than once?

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

In Divinity: Original Sin 2, the only way to break the  deal with God King is to use this special weapon. There are two of those present in the game: one in three pieces (plan in the Blackgates in 2nd act, blade in the Academy in 3rd act, and the haft kept by the Sallow Man, also in 3rd act), one you get near the end of the game in Arx.

But there are quite a few people that could benefit from it: Windego, Red Princess, Almira and... you, if you've decided to take the deal.

Can you use the two available Swornbreakers to release all those people,  or do you have to make a choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to make a choice.
Not only will each of the NPCs keep the Swornbreaker if you decide to help them, the weapon will also crumble to dust if you use it to free yourself of the Covenant. There's no way to help every person who regrets their pact, unfortunately.

Comment: You are right - to a degree: you can use Swornbreaker on yourself and then give it to Windego.

Comment: Is that so? That sounds more like a bug than intended, but I'll try it out.

Comment: There are methods to get the Swornbreaker back after freeing a NPC, but there are more akin to wallhacks than RP solutions.

Comment: Not entirely correct. If you give the Swornbreaker to Winedo she uses it and you can loot it off of her remains. It does have 0/20 durability however.

Comment: @Parrotmaster Not from what I remember.

Comment: @Wrigglenite I did it literally yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's possible if you have no problem with taking advantage of some glitches.

> I was on PS4, by initiating the conversation with NPC and then drop the sword on the ground before they take it. You will be able to gain an extra use.

Answer (score 2):

You can also sell a broken Swornbreaker to Fletcher Corbin Day prior to going to Arx and it will be repaired on arrival.